# How to config 2 interface with pptp?

Tags: centos, nat, pptp, interface

In this topic [Which is the best OS for PPTP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/226073/which-is-the-best-os-for-pptp) :

> server with this CPU and 2 Intel
>   PRO/1000 network adapters really
>   handles ~2 hour peak of 250MBit/s
>   internet traffic on one interface and
>   sends all this traffic encapsulated in
>   PPTP via another interface.

I want to know how to use 2 interface on PPTP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bond the interfaces and use them as a single interface. With the right equipment you get double the throughput, or redundancy, or both.

Comment: so how to bond the interfaces ?

Comment: [How to bond interfaces in Linux](http://www.linux-corner.info/bonding.html), though there's more to know that just that. You may want to hire a consultant who knows what they're getting in to.